Dataframe from wide to long output
original wide data frame mean_SRBD:

I have a data frame (mean_SRBD). The measurement moments (day 1, day 2, day 3) are included in the suffix of the variables (-D1 = day 1, -D2 = day 2). I want to go from a wide to a long output. Using the code using melt I get an error, but I cannot resolve it to go to the next output. How do I solve the error code? Alternative code?
target long output data frame:

library(reshape2)
library(dplyr)

long_data <- melt(
mean_SRBD,
id.vars = "Subject.ID",
measure.vars = starts_with(c("MeanAanD", "MeanUvD", "TotFreqD", "NyctD")),  
var.name = "variable",
value.name = "value"
)
long_data$day <- gsub("[a-z]+", "", long_data$variable)
 
print(long_data)


Please do not post images of data. Instead use the dput() command on your data and copy-paste the output to your question. This will make it easier for us to access your data and provide more exact help.

Something like this should work: library(tidyr); pivot_longer(df, matches("D\\d+$"), names_pattern = c("(.*)D(\\d+$)"), names_to = c(".value", "day"), names_transform = list(day = as.numeric))

If you're using melt, then you may want to use the data.table package instead of reshape2. In that case, you can use patterns for the "measure.vars":
library(data.table)

setDT(mean_SRBD)

long_data <- melt(
  mean_SRBD,
  id.vars = "Subject.ID",
  measure.vars = patterns("^MeanAanD", "^MeanUvD", "^TotFreqD"),
  variable.name="day",
  value.name = c("MeanAanD","MeanUvD","TotFreqD"),
)


long_data
    Subject.ID    day MeanAanD MeanUvD TotFreqD
         <num> <fctr>    <num>   <num>    <num>
 1:      1.012      1        1       0       14
 2:      1.014      1        2       2        7
 3:      1.021      1        2       1       10
 4:      1.022      1        3       1        6
 5:      1.024      1        2       2        9
 6:      1.030      1        2       0        9
 7:      1.031      1        3       1        5
 8:      1.012      2        2       1       12
 9:      1.014      2        3       2        5
10:      1.021      2        2       1        8
11:      1.022      2        2       1        2
12:      1.024      2        3       0        3
13:      1.030      2        2       1       10
14:      1.031      2        1       2       12
15:      1.012      3        2       2       13
16:      1.014      3        3       2        8
17:      1.021      3        2       2        6
18:      1.022      3        2       1        8
19:      1.024      3        3       0        9
20:      1.030      3        2       1       12
21:      1.031      3        1       0       11
    Subject.ID    day MeanAanD MeanUvD TotFreqD


mean_SRBD <- structure(list(Subject.ID = c(1.012, 1.014, 1.021, 1.022, 1.024, 
1.03, 1.031), MeanAanD1 = c(1, 2, 2, 3, 2, 2, 3), MeanAanD2 = c(2, 
3, 2, 2, 3, 2, 1), MeanAanD3 = c(2, 3, 2, 2, 3, 2, 1), MeanUvD1 = c(0, 
2, 1, 1, 2, 0, 1), MeanUvD2 = c(1, 2, 1, 1, 0, 1, 2), MeanUvD3 = c(2, 
2, 2, 1, 0, 1, 0), TotFreqD1 = c(14, 7, 10, 6, 9, 9, 5), TotFreqD2 = c(12, 
5, 8, 2, 3, 10, 12), TotFreqD3 = c(13, 8, 6, 8, 9, 12, 11)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-7L))


It worked, thanks!

Don't forget to accept and upvote. :-)
